# Add caching for existing LVM

Tags: linux, lvm

my AlmaLinux 9.3 server currently uses LVM.

One VG is mapped to the system SSD drive, consists of two LV, root and swap. This is fine as it is.

One VG consist of three hard-drives and is called Vault. It's just data storage, mounted at /vault. If the Docker services run on the server are shutdown and the LV can be disabled without interfering with the basic OS.

I witnessed a lot of wa in top in specific situations lately. One cheap idea of fixing this would be introducing an SSD cache for the existing LVM vault config. After purchasing an SSD drive (which has not been installed yet), I realised that most of the guides describe the process of integrating cache at installation time. I looked at the RHEL, this very good written overview (from a German IT blog) and others like them. Most of them warn about data existing on the Vault would be lost when introducing a cache drive to the existing LVM.

I extended the vault twice yet, but not with a cache.

Can anyone share their experience doing this or point to proper documentation ? I do not have enough external storage available to back-up all the data. I just back-up the crucial stuff, but it would be very annoying to lose the other data.

Relevant output

```
pvdisplay:
--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc2
  VG Name               system
  PV Size               207.88 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              53217
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          53217
  PV UUID               JUC0bk-nF8l-YQmR-GZnn-zzvo-pes3-t6rjud
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdd1
  VG Name               vault
  PV Size               <9.10 TiB / not usable 2.98 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2384383
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          2384383
  PV UUID               oSUiba-13Zq-Ug7I-Ggwk-aCs4-HeIy-mL8b55
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda
  VG Name               vault
  PV Size               <7.28 TiB / not usable <1.34 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1907721
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          1907721
  PV UUID               W3nnD4-LbDZ-krY8-KVOZ-jnl0-1Khb-C56F6W
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               vault
  PV Size               <20.01 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5245439
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          5245439
  PV UUID               1YIaLl-DRtM-vMAS-1SKb-6iUg-87Gv-2BgnJ1

vgdisplay:
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               system
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <207.88 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              53217
  Alloc PE / Size       53217 / <207.88 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               BHmjRL-1pC6-Y5FY-tDBd-ID5P-Vvcl-jvmpzA
   
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vault
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        3
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                3
  Act PV                3
  VG Size               36.38 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              9537543
  Alloc PE / Size       9537543 / 36.38 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               Bi5H7i-FWY5-kMEN-K7aK-0NST-TKjP-sZnpMY

lvdisplay:
 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/system/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                system
  LV UUID                Ju9Hve-q3xe-YYa7-msvG-EelX-wQdh-vrMrcS
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time core, 2023-01-03 15:00:41 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <191.88 GiB
  Current LE             49121
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/system/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                system
  LV UUID                SVDs7q-QjNu-LN1W-4Bjm-psC3-kXbH-l6SdZa
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xxx, 2023-01-03 15:00:41 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                16.00 GiB
  Current LE             4096
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vault/vault
  LV Name                vault
  VG Name                vault
  LV UUID                Gxzis5-NCCX-FhQa-e2rv-FNcn-nQpt-7Ni0fV
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xxx, 2019-06-04 22:07:37 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                36.38 TiB
  Current LE             9537543
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper documentation is `man lvmcache` on your system. There is also RHEL documentation [Enabling caching to improve logical volume performance](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/enabling-caching-to-improve-logical-volume-performance_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes).

If you are unsure, you can always try the procedure in a VM.

And always have backups of your data.